# Methods to detect fraudulent test data

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, fraud-detection

I work for a company that manufactures widgets and we test each widget before it leaves the factory. One of the parameters that we ask our testers to manually record is the cycle time. Lately I've been suspecting that some (not all) testers are falsifying their cycle time reading and I'm trying to do some "official" statistical analysis to determine whether or not the values they are recording are possible.

Some background:
Expected cycle time is 4m0s to 6m30s. This range was set by finding the mean/std dev of previously collected data a few years back then setting the specification limits to +/-2 sigma rounded to the nearest "nice" number.

Here's what that distribution looks like:

[image]

There are some obvious issues there: mean of data doesn't actually correspond to the center of the specifications, big cliff at 4m0s where testers are (probably) rounding up, then some values (ie: multiples of 5s) appearing more frequently than expected. There are some oddities that appear when the data is broken out by employee:

[image]

I've normalized the frequency of the values being reported by the total number of data points that a tester has provided.

Just looking at this data, I can "see" that the bottom four distributions are pretty blatantly false. The middle right reported 30% of their readings as 4:58,4:59,5:01,5:02 (but not as 5:00). The middle left has lots of values rounded to the nearest 5s.

I've also done a frequency analysis of the last digit of the reported values. It looks like over such a range the probability of any last digit is nearly ~0.10.

Some testers are pretty good about that (they have distributions of the last digit at 8~12%), but then the testers that have bad looking distributions also favor some numbers more than others (ie: the last digit is "5" 20% of the time)

The actual question:

Is there any sort of statistical approach that I can take to say "yup, the probability of this kind of distribution is 1 in 100 billion"? Any recommended reading or other techniques for this?

Thanks!

Comment: The use of Excel to smooth the data is obscuring very important features of the data: these plots don't match your descriptions of the data.  I see nothing at all in the plots that looks, solely on its merits, like fraud--it is easy to imagine innocent explanations of all the non-Normal characteristics in the distributions.  If you could choose more faithful ways to display or summarize the data, that might help people identify good approaches.

Comment: Even if you find apparent impossibilities in the data, I wouldn't rush to the assumption of malfeasance. It's more likely that testers made mistakes. See [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon's_razor).

Comment: @whuber, I've changed the charts to bar charts. Also, all of the data is available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ix-8LPxuhZFL5cIvkERblpNvUN2FGMeuPjZ__oXiCoo/pubhtml) if anyone is curious to look at it.

Charts correspond to the following columns:
Top Left:        3
Top Right:      17
Middle Left:    7
Middle Right:  10
Bottom Left:    1
Bottom Right:  11

Comment: Thank you for making your charts much clearer.  Although there definitely are differences among the distributions, much depends on understanding exactly how this "cycle time" is supposed to behave, as well as the circumstances under which each individual is testing.  Maybe there is a natural floor to the time and maybe some individuals are testing under varying circumstances.  If you do not have a formal procedure to assign subjects randomly to the testers, such possibilities have to be seriously considered.

Comment: @whuber, the cycle time is the time it takes for the device to go from a start temperature to an end temperature. The testers turn on the machine then use a simple stop watch to record the time when the machine reaches the final teperature.

There's a minimum cycle time of some sort (probably ~3min in the most ideal circumstances), but the floor at 4m0s that's visible in the data is most definitely due to testers not wanting our QA people to reject the results because they were out of spec. Machines are assigned randomly to testers to test though..